# db is not importing correctly, what am I missing

Tags: python-3.x

I know that this questions has been asked numerous times but I can't find what my issue is. I am new to python so this is some of the issue.

I am following a tutorial and it's required to do import app from db on terminal in PyCharm
but when I run that command I get the error of

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLAlchemy_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
app.config['SQLAlchemy_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
# from app import bd , db.create_all()
# C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectFinal\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py
db.init_app(app)

class Camper(db.model):

    id=db.column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name=db.column(db.string(20), nullable=False)
    LastN=db.column(db.string(20), nullable=False)
    PhoneNumber=db.column(db.Integer(9), default=0)
    Agedb=db.column(db.Integer, default=0)
    CampingTime=db.column(db.string(20), nullable=False)
    IsAllergic=db.column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    date_created = db.column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Task %r>' % self.id


@app.route("/", method=['POST', 'GET'])
def hello():
    if request.method=='POST':
        camper_etails=request.form['content']
        new_camper= Camper(content=camper_etails)
        try:
            db.session.add(new_camper)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return'there was an issue adding info'
    else:
        registered=Camper.query.order_by(Camper.date_created).all()
        return render_template('index.html', registered=registered)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

@app.route("/delete/<int:id>/")
def delete(id):
    deletea= Camper.quary.get_or_404(id)
    try:
        db.session.delete(deletea)
        db.session.commit()
        redirect('/')

    except:
        return'there was a problem deleting'


@app.route("/about")
def aboutpage():
    return "<h1>this is the about page!<h1>"


@app.route('/users/<int:id>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_info(id):
    registered=Camper.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        registered.content = request.form['content']
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return 'problem accord'
    else:
        render_template('update.html', registered=registered)
```

when I tried to import it I saw that app is not a module that can be imported so it must be a different issue

Comment: The error is about line 1, which for sure it is not something you included. Please: be more precise, else we cannot help. Which lines gives you an error? (and on the code you post, not on other code)

Comment: my question is not about the code, it's about importing db from app.
 I posted the code so it should be clear what the purpose of the import is,
 but I need instructions how to get the import to work because I cannot create a database without it.
how can I get the import right?
 what do I need to provide so I am clearer?